# Is there a recommended way to get spring boot to JSON format logs with logback

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-logback, logz.io

Using spring boot `2.1.1.RELEASE` one can seemingly format logs as JSON by providing a `logback-spring.xml` file as follows:

```
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
            <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX</timestampFormat>
            <timestampFormatTimezoneId>Etc/UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>
            <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
            </jsonFormatter>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</root>
```

and adding to the `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

indeed leading to messages like:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2018-12-11T18:20:25.641Z",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "thread" : "main",
  "logger" : "com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource",
  "message" : "To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.",
  "context" : "default"
}
```

## Why?

I'm trialing [logz.io](https://logz.io) which appears to behave more favourably when logs are JSON formatted, some o the shippers struggle with multiline logs like we see in java stack traces and when formatting in JSON it can automatically parse fields like `level` and `message` and if there is MDC data it automatically gets that.

I had some not so great experiences with a few of the methods of shipping logs to logzio, like their docker image and using rsyslog without using JSON formatted log messages.

## Issues With This Approach

It works ok for console appending, but spring boot provides like `logging.file=test.log`, `logging.level.com.example=WARN`, `logging.pattern.console`. I can indeed import the managed configuration from `spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml` which in turn imports a `console-appender.xml and`file-appender.xml`.

### An example of the console-appender

```
<included>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</included>
```

### An example of the file appender

```
<included>
    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY:-0}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
</included>
```

These two are exactly what I need to support spring configuration of the properties, but they don't include the encoder/layout I'd need.

It appears in my initial tests that I can't simple name my appender the same as those and provide my layouts. For example:

```
<configuration>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX</timestampFormat>
                <timestampFormatTimezoneId>Etc/UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>
                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
                </jsonFormatter>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>



    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

leads to the message being logged in both JSON and plain text format.

I can indeed just copy and paste the contents of these 3 files into my custom config rather than import them at all. Then I may override what I want to customise.

However, as spring evolves and new releases are made which may add features, I'd be forever forcing myself to keep up, copy and paste the new files and make my changes and test them.

Is there any better way that I can either:

- Just make additive changes to the appenders rather than entirely redefine them, e.g. keep the config from spring but provide my own encoder or layout to be used by those appenders.
- Configure spring to JSON log via properties entirely without any config - I doubt this :S

---

Footnote: logzio do provide [a dependency](https://app.logz.io/#/dashboard/data-sources/Java--logbackappender) one can import, but I dislike the idea of coupling the logging provider into the code directly. I feel that if the servoce happens to produce JSON logs to stdout or a file, it's easy for any provider to process those and ship them to some destination.

Answer (score 30):

I am not using any dependency.
Simply, doing it via application.yml, that's all.
This solution solves, multiline log issue, too.

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "{\"time\": \"%d\", \"level\": \"%p\", \"correlation-id\": \"%X{X-Correlation-Id}\", \"source\": \"%logger{63}:%L\", \"message\": \"%replace(%m%wEx{6}){'[\r\n]+', '\\n'}%nopex\"}%n"
```

Comment: Works great for me, thanks. A note - had to remove `Correlation-Id`, as it is not out of the box in Spring Boot

Comment: This will break if the log message includes double-quotes.

Comment: We are using `application.properties` file. `\\n` did not work for us. Instead, this worked for us: `%replace(%message){'\n', '\\\\n'}`.

Comment: For message that includes double-quotes, this can work: `{"message": "%replace(%replace(%message){'\n', '\\\\n'}){'"', '\\\\"'}"}`

Comment: @NileshKevlani where should we replace the `{"message": "%replace(%replace(%message){'\n', '\\\\n'}){'"', '\\\\"'}"}` in given answer. Can you please share whole pattern which includes double-quotes

Comment: Hey, in my use case, I was using `application.properties` file and I was setting this property like this: `logging.pattern.console={"message": "%replace(%replace(%message){'\n', '\\\\n'}){'"', '\\\\"'}"}`

Answer (score 5):

I use something like the following, has always worked fine.

Spring Boot recommendation is to name the file `logback-spring.xml` and place it under `src/main/resources/`, this enables us to use spring profiles in logback.
So in the file below you will see that for `LOCAL` profile you can log in the standard fashion but for the deployments on the server or a container you can you a different logging strategy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [YourApp:%thread:%X{X-B3-TraceId}:%X{X-B3-SpanId}] %logger{40} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="jsonstdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <providers>
                <timestamp>
                    <timeZone>EST</timeZone>
                </timestamp>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "level": "%level",
                        "service": "YourApp",
                        "traceId": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
                        "spanId": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
                        "thread": "%thread",
                        "class": "%logger{40}",
                        "message": "%message"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>
                <stackTrace>
                    <throwableConverter class="net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter">
                        <maxDepthPerThrowable>30</maxDepthPerThrowable>
                        <maxLength>2048</maxLength>
                        <shortenedClassNameLength>20</shortenedClassNameLength>
                        <rootCauseFirst>true</rootCauseFirst>
                    </throwableConverter>
                </stackTrace>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
    <springProfile name="LOCAL">
      <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </springProfile>
    <springProfile name="!LOCAL">
      <appender-ref ref="jsonstdout" />
    </springProfile>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post an example @Chad . I have had no problems. We have about 30 microservices and no issues so far. Best part is a readable stack trace

Comment: if you logged the string `I have a quote ".` I think it would break the json because the quote wouldn't be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to copy paste with modifications 3 out of 4 files from here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.1.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback into your configuration.

The good news is that you don't need to copy paste https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml

That can be included like so `<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/default.xml"/>`

That will get you some of spring's default config without copying and pasting

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to log4j2 using the method specified in the Spring Boot documentation

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"
modules {
  module("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging") {
    replacedBy("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2", "Use Log4j2 instead of Logback")
  }
}
```

You can have a file log4j2.properties that contains the following.

```
appender.stdout.type=Console
appender.stdout.name=json
appender.stdout.json.type=JsonTemplateLayout
appender.stdout.json.eventTemplateUri=classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=console
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=${env:LOGGING_APPENDER:-json}
```

I used `LOGGING_APPENDER` to match my environment level overrides.

Note one odd flaw though... this does not work when you're on JDK17.

**UPDATE for Spring boot 3.x, but you still cannot control the logging via env vars**

*log4j-spring.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="json" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="json"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And these depenedencies

```kotlin
    runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2")
    runtimeOnly("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-layout-template-json")
    modules {
        module("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging") {
            replacedBy("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2", "Use Log4j2 instead of Logback")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is for using Logback with one additional dependency

```kotlin
runtimeOnly("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.4")
```

And `logback-spring.xml` which contains

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <appender name="JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" />
    </appender>
    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="${LOGGING_APPENDER:-JSON}"/>
    </root>
    <!-- this silences warnings when the appenders are not active -->
    <logger name="nil">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="JSON"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```